# What is the meaning of || symbol in circuit analysis equations?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I cannot figure out the meaning of the logical OR ( || )  in this context.

Rin = R1 +R2||R4

[image]
in this circuit

[image]

This was taken from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uir9Js1l_r8

*at around 6:00 of the video

Comment: + means series and || or // has an analog meaning not the same as logical OR AND XOR symbols..  1 / (R2//R4) = 1 / R2+ 1 / R4  (it means parallel )

Comment: Basic research: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+%7C%7C+mean+in+electronics&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&oq=what+does+%7C%7C+mean+in+electronics&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i22i30l8.11703j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the parallel equivalent between \$R_2\$ and \$R_4\$. Actually in this circuit it's only valid since \$R_4\$ is much greater than \$R_3\$, so you can ignore \$R_3\$ and end up with \$R_2 ||R_4\$.